# Excel COM add in location

Tags: c#, excel, installation, add-in

I have created a visual studio installer project for an excel Add-in written in C#. I followed the steps described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654.aspx). After successful installation, the add-in is shown as 'not loaded' when opening the Excel and no error message is shown regarding this.

It won't work without 'file:///' in front of the add in location in Manifest registry value. The 'registry' in the installer project looks like this: 
[image]

What is the difference between having 'file:///' and not having it in Excel Addin location?
[image]

Comment: Most obvious explanation is that you forgot to set the LoadBehavior registry key.  Next most obvious is that it bombed when it loaded.  Add logging so you can see it loading and use try/catch to get a diagnostic when an exception is thrown.

Comment: I had set 3 to LoadBehavior registry. Setting it to 2 didn't show me the error either.